# How to extract a sample of objects from array of nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, extract, javascript-objects

i'm developing in Javascript and i created `folders` array that contain objects:

```
folders = [folder1, folder2, folder3...]
```

Every object have some properties, one of this is `docs` that is an array of objects:

```
docs = [doc1, doc2, doc3...]
```

...and every object is like this:

```
doc1.title = 'foo'
doc1.desc = 'bar'
doc1.attr = {new: _.random(0, 1) > 0.5, read: _.random(0, 1) > 0.5}
...
```

I would like to create a function that extract only docs that have `attr = {new: true, read: false}`.
I tried some underscore method such as `_.each`, `_.sample`, `_.find` and `_.findWhere`, but i can't figure out how to get from the main array a sample that contains docs with that `attr` properties.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you give us more code? Like what did you try with lodash `.find()`? Wouldn't a regular loop do the work?

Comment: remark: do not use `new` without quotes as a key of object. use `"new"` instead.

Comment: I added a working JSFiddle to my answer, tell me if it fits your needs.

Comment: Did you find a solution that fits you needs?

Answer (score 1):

Using underscore first [**flatten**](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten) the folders and then use [**where**](http://underscorejs.org/#where) to get what you want:

```
var result = _.where( _.flatten(folders), {new: true, read: false});
```

**Edited** to work with the new structure:

```
var result = _.chain(folders)
    .pluck('docs')
    .flatten()
    .where({isNew: true, read: false})
    .value();
```

```js
var folders = [
 {
  docs: [    
   {
    title: 'one',
    isNew: true,
    read: false
   },    {
    title: 'two',
    isNew: true,
    read: true
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  docs: 
  [
   {
    title: 'three',
    isNew: false,
    read: false
   },    {
    title: 'four',
    isNew: true,
    read: false
   }
  ]
 }
];

var result = _.chain(folders)
 .pluck('docs')
 .flatten()
 .where({isNew: true, read: false})
 .value();

document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore.js"></script>

<p>
  <pre id="result"></pre>
</p>
```

Comment: I didn't know `_.flatten`, anyway i was wrong and i edited my answer. Can you make your way working with the new structure?

Comment: Underscore or lodash are not really required here, but this should work indeed.

Comment: Apart from when you don't want to reinvent the wheel and when you want to support older browsers.

Comment: It doens't work, anyway it doesn't matter because i found a solution. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Added a code snippet and also changed the code to reflect that the doc property `new` is now called `isNew`.

Answer (score 0):

What about a regular filter?

### [Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a2qLu5cp/)

(Simply open your browser console and run the fiddle.)

```
doc1.filter(o => o.attr.new && !o.attr.read)
```

And you can also simply `map()` your `folders` array.

```
const _folders = folders
  .map(doc => doc.filter(o => o.attr.new && !o.attr.read))
```

You would get on new folders array containing arrays with only `new && !read` documents. Which you could flatten if needed:

```
const flatFolders = [].concat.apply([], _folders)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
var result = [];
folders.forEach(function(docs) {
    result.concat( docs.filter(function(doc) {
        return doc.attr.new && !doc.attr.read;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

underscore methods like `.find` work on arrays which are one level deep:

```
 var temp = [];
_.each(folders , function(docsArray){
    var result = _.where(docsArray ,  {new: true, read: false});
    if(result){
        temp.concat(result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want **without** using **underscore** or **lodash**,just 
Take advantage of the built-in `Array.map` and `Array.filter` methods, here is an example :

```
var myResult = folders.map(function(folder){

      return myCustomDocs = folder.filter(function(doc){
            return (doc.attr.new  && !doc.attr.read);
      });
});

console.log(myResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Node.js 5+ or use [Babel](http://babeljs.io/), you can just do:

```
folders.reduce((res, arr) => res.concat(arr), [])      // flatten folders
       .filter(doc => doc.attr.new && !doc.attr.read); // remove all that don't return true
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution.
Here is my code:

```
var result = [];
folders.forEach(function(item) {
    result = result.concat(_.filter(item.docs, function(doc) {
        return doc.isNew === true && doc.read === false;
    }));
});
```